How can I best join more than two curves in Geometry Nodes?
I am trying to join three curves that are part of the same figure (joined using the join geometry tool). When I use the merge by distance tool, the join is correct if I merge any two of the three curves. However, if I try to join all three, the join appears with an extra length. It seems that the third curve distorts the join. Is there a solution to this problem?

You gave yourself an answer : merge one curve after the other. Plus, I don't understand the "extra length" and "distort the join" you are talking about.

It all depends on what kind of effect you want to achieve. A curve is defined by an array of points, so you can just glue multiple arrays together and reinterpret as curves:

Of course the points can have various attributes that you may want to keep - for example you may want not to evaluate the beziers into polys (many straight segments) and keep the handle coordinates:


I made the order between the splines awkward on purpose - there's no logic for changing an order of splines that would be generally useful. Here you could want to sort by $y$ coordinate, but then you could also want to reverse every 2nd spline for example…
