Geometry Nodes conform array to curve - stretches when using multiple curves
I followed Erindale's Curve Deform tutorial (https://youtu.be/uv0E_FQLQYI?si=9VAH5HPmUdYv3C_y) which shows you how to deform an object along a curve (as the name suggests).
I'm trying to extend it so that an array of objects (Suzanne for testing) is created automatically with the ideal number of Suzannes needed to prevent any stretching.
I've been pretty successful with the setup shown below, except when there's multiple curves that aren't attached - you can see a Suzanne is getting stretched between them. This can sometimes be fixed by adding some spacing between the objects in the array, but that defeats the purpose of this exercise as I plan to use it to extend things continuously along a curve (e.g. pipes etc).
If anyone has any suggestions on how I could avoid the stretching I would be grateful.
(Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10zEV5pzTGtdKzkI0smWneRqXwZqBU-8-/view?usp=sharing)



Does it answer your question ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/321536/how-can-i-best-join-more-than-two-curves-in-geometry-nodes

Do you want the monkeys to span between the curves or not?

Sorry guys wasn't clear, I don't want any objects between the curves. For example if there's three curves, the end result should be three separate arrays of monkeys, all following the curves, with nothing in-between. So stitching the curves together won't help
